# How to check and use the status of cp command in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, cp

This is a statement in my shell script. ${origin} and ${archive} are 2 directories.

The command reads all jpg, png and jpeg files within the ${origin} folder and copy them to ${archive} folder.

```
find ${origin} -regex '.*\(jpg\|png\|jpeg\)' -exec cp -n {} ${archive} \;
```

What I want is that if cp successfully copy a file, ( also indicates that the file does not exist in ${archive} folder), it will execute some commands.

Questions:

1. How can I know whether cp successfully copy the file, in the shell script?
2. Where can I place the if statement?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `find -exec` says:

> Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.

"true" in this context means what the result of the `-exec` command will be, which controls whether processing of the matched file will continue.  So you can do this:

```
find ... -exec cp -n {} ${archive} \; -exec OTHER STUFF \;
```

That is, first attempt to copy the file.  If `cp` succeeds it will return `0` which `find` will treat as `true` meaning "keep processing this file."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved my problem perfectly. Is it possible to check if the cp command overwrite existing file in shell script?

Comment: You can use a command like `-exec test -f ${archive}/{} \;` which will continue processing only if the file already exists in the target.  Put a `!` in front of `test` to invert the check.